# how to cell size increse or resize on the button click?

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a custom table view that contains 2 buttons dynamically in cell for row index path ,

i want to when i click for increase size should be increased and button should be hide , and

then one button for resize row height should be visible - Thanks in Advance .

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 


    return JcOutCellSize;

    }  


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
// ----------------------- cellbackground image-----------------------------   

    cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 151, 320, 108)];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"inCellFullBg.png"]]; 

//***********  Change Cell BackGround  Colour*****


    // cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];







//----------------------------Cell buttons-------------------------------------------  

     if (JcOutCellSize==152)
     {
    UIButton *AddComment = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; // custom means transparent it takes shape same with backgroup image
    [AddComment addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(TestBtns:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    // [AddComment setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    AddComment.frame = CGRectMake(9.0, 128.0, 96.0, 26.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:AddComment];

    UIImage *buttonAddComment = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addcomment.png"];
    [AddComment setBackgroundImage:buttonAddComment forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:AddComment]; 

     }


    if (JcOutCellSize==152)
    {
        NSLog(@" up arrow %f",JcOutCellSize);
        UIButton *UpArrow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [UpArrow addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(ResizeCell:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        //[DownArrow setTitle:@"Arrow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UpArrow.frame = CGRectMake(143.0, 136.0, 26.0, 16.0);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:UpArrow];

        UIImage *buttonUp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upArrow.png"];
        [UpArrow setBackgroundImage:buttonUp forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:UpArrow];   
        NSLog(@" cell size = %f",JcOutCellSize);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    if (JcOutCellSize==132)
    {
        NSLog(@" down arrow %f",JcOutCellSize);
        UIButton *DownArrow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [DownArrow addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(IncreseCellHight:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        //[DownArrow setTitle:@"Arrow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        DownArrow.frame = CGRectMake(143.0, 116.0, 26.0, 16.0);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:DownArrow];

        UIImage *buttondown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upDownArrow.png"];
        [DownArrow setBackgroundImage:buttondown forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:DownArrow]; 
        NSLog(@" cell size = %f",JcOutCellSize);
    }




       return cell;
    }
```

in view didload i have done this JcOutCellSize=152;

Comment: you duplicate `if (JcOutCellSize==152)`

Comment: pls tell me more , its for checking condition and executes suitable code .

Answer (score 0):

To change row height by button click, you should do the following steps:
1. Create some flag that will indicate which row is expanded, for example _expandedIndexPath

1. Implement correct datasource method like that:

   ```
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath { 

   if (_expandedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath) {
       return JcBigCellSize; // large cell
   }
   else
       return JcOutCellSize; // normal cell
   }
   ```
2. To define on which cell button was pressed, set tag of the button to corresponding indexPath.row (in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)
3. On button action (IncreseCellHight:) get the tag of the button, 
   set _expandedIndexPath to the indexpath, which you want to see expanded (most likely [NSindexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]) 
   and reload corresponding row using UITableView's method reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

This will call datasource methods for this row (tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:), and your cell will increase it's height with animation, specified in withRowAnimation: parameter.